# Connection to RocketChat refused on GCE Instance

Tags: google-compute-engine, rocket.chat

I'm trying to set up a Rocket Chat server on a micro GCE instance (micro, Always-Free). 
I've installed Rocket.Chat via snapd with no problems (SSH access). The service is up and running, and the external IP is ping-able.

The port that RocketChat uses is 3000, and I've created the needed firewall rules:

```
inbound - all instances - IP Range 0.0.0.0/0 - tcp:3000 - allow - priority 1
inbound - all instances - IP Range 0.0.0.0/0 - udp:3000 - allow - priority 2
```

However, when I try to connect via browser I get a "refused". What am I missing?

Answer (score -1):

You need to add [firewall rule on GCP](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/using-firewalls#creating_firewall_rules) to allow ingress port 3000 (tcp and udp) to your VPC Network where is your GCE instance, you can add firewall rule by using the [gcloud command](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/compute/firewall-rules/create) as well see below:

```
gcloud compute firewall-rules create [name]  --action allow --rules tcp:3000,udp:3000 --direction INGRESS --network [VPC_NAME]
```

I succeeded to create a RocketChat with snapd using micro instance with Allow HTTP traffic enabled (it was a Debian)
Did follow the step [here](https://rocket.chat/docs/installation/manual-installation/ubuntu/snaps/)

```
sudo apt-get install snapd
sudo snap install rocketchat-server
```

Then checked the status of the server

```
sudo service snap.rocketchat-server.rocketchat-server status
```

Output:

```
$ sudo service snap.rocketchat-server.rocketchat-server status
        ● snap.rocketchat-server.rocketchat-server.service - Service for snap application rocketchat-server.rocketchat-server
       Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/snap.rocketchat-server.rocketchat-server.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
       Active: active (running) since Wed 2019-01-09 21:14:25 UTC; 14min ago
     Main PID: 6148 (startRocketChat)
        Tasks: 12 (limit: 4915)
       CGroup: /system.slice/snap.rocketchat-server.rocketchat-server.service
               ├─6148 /bin/bash /snap/rocketchat-server/1356/bin/startRocketChat
               └─6165 node /snap/rocketchat-server/1356/main.js

    Jan 09 21:14:44 rocketchat rocketchat-server.rocketchat-server[6148]: ➔ |  Rocket.Chat Version: 0.72.3            |
    Jan 09 21:14:44 rocketchat rocketchat-server.rocketchat-server[6148]: ➔ |       NodeJS Version: 8.11.3 - x64      |
    Jan 09 21:14:44 rocketchat rocketchat-server.rocketchat-server[6148]: ➔ |             Platform: linux             |
    Jan 09 21:14:44 rocketchat rocketchat-server.rocketchat-server[6148]: ➔ |         Process Port: 3000              |
    Jan 09 21:14:44 rocketchat rocketchat-server.rocketchat-server[6148]: ➔ |             Site URL: http://localhost  |
    Jan 09 21:14:44 rocketchat rocketchat-server.rocketchat-server[6148]: ➔ |     ReplicaSet OpLog: Enabled           |
    Jan 09 21:14:44 rocketchat rocketchat-server.rocketchat-server[6148]: ➔ |          Commit Hash: 65747ce814        |
    Jan 09 21:14:44 rocketchat rocketchat-server.rocketchat-server[6148]: ➔ |        Commit Branch: HEAD              |
    Jan 09 21:14:44 rocketchat rocketchat-server.rocketchat-server[6148]: ➔ |                                         |
    Jan 09 21:14:44 rocketchat rocketchat-server.rocketchat-server[6148]: ➔ +-----------------------------------------+
```

The `curl localhost:3000` was successful but not the external IP `curl [EXTERNAL_IP]:3000`.

Then Added the Firewall rule above (using the gcloud command or the console it's up to you), and I were able then to curl my external IP and was able to browser using my EXTERNAL_IP:3000 for the setup wizard.

You can also deploy Rocket.Chat with docker see this [documentation](https://rocket.chat/docs/installation/paas-deployments/google-computer-engine/)

Comment: The rules have already been created on the 'default' network (that is the one my instance is using)

Comment: see above steps and my reproduction